# Manga where a boy gets an invitation to test out a VR game

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga before but forgot the name of it. It's relatively new.

So, he gets stuck inside the game and can't leave until he finishes the level. The person he has to defeat is overpowered and the boy is always the last one on the battlefield with this girl she swore to protect him. Every time she is about to say something to him, she dies, so every time he dies, he resurrects and grows stronger while the developer tries to make his will break. If his will breaks, the game ends.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, do you recall the hair colour of the boy and the girl?

Comment: This sounds like Sword Art Online, but I'm only passingly familiar with the series.

Comment: @Shadur He wasn't invited to test in that game and got lucky to score a beta testing copy. Also people didn't get stuck un the game until after it was released and they had to beat the game to leave and dying in the game or getting disconnected in any way meant dying in real life

Comment: @LogicDictates it had a unique art style, i had color in it, im pretty sure his hair was black and the i think the girls hair was purple if i recall.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely *[Knight Under My Heart](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/knight-under-my-heart)*. It is available on [tappytoon](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/comics/knight-under-my-heart) and [webtoons](https://www.webtoons.com/en/action/knight-under-my-heart/list?title_no=4215).

> Have you ever skipped studying to play video games? Unfortunately for high school senior Yushin Lee, the stakes are a little higher than flunking, as **he finds himself trapped in a VR-based MMORPG**. Yushin was selected to beta test the game, only to be **forced to fight for his life in a seemingly endless loop**. What was supposed to be a light distraction from the stress of high-school life becomes a desperate struggle for survival as Yushin battles his way through REAL Online, a dark fantasy world created by a mysterious tech company with uncertain motives.

The synopsis covers much of the question. The main character is selected to be a beta tester for a VR game with specialized equipment, and is trapped in the game by the evil game developers. The only part of the game shown is a battlefield with a huge number of soldiers, plus a giant man named Bracken that repeatedly kills the main character, resetting the loop.

The purple haired girl appears at the end of chapter 5; she tells him that this shouldn't be treated as a game, and is immediately killed by Bracken. This does not appear to be a recurring thing, just the one time. She has no difficulty trying to teach him to fight at the end of chapter 8.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag combination `virtual reality` and `trapped in a video game`